# Media library project using Angular

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

Recently I created a small project: 'media library' (which allow to search, sort and filter items) and I will be glad if some give me constructive feedback about my code. The starting point is **Angular-CLI**, and the full code with starting page is [HERE](https://github.com/kamil-kielczewski/media-library/tree/c13ca5cbf7151f02245c16d9ab602375ff99a298/src/app/pages/media-library/media-library-presenter.component.ts). And below is 'main' model used in app

[image]

Here are all files which I add/change

file: **media-library//src/index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MediaLibrary</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  
    <!-- KK: usually we copy fonts to angular project, but here it is not 
    important so we donwload them on front side -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha256-46qynGAkLSFpVbEBog43gvNhfrOj+BmwXdxFgVK/Kvc=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

file: **media-library//src/app/directives/click-outside.directive.ts**

```js
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @Output()
  public clickOutside = new EventEmitter < MouseEvent > ();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
  public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
    if (!targetElement) {
      return;
    }

    const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!clickedInside) {
      this.clickOutside.emit(event);
    }
  }
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/app.component.html**

```js
<!-- 
KK: Here we usually create layout which contains e.g. menu, top bar... which 
comunicate with pages by global events - but for simplicity we ommit global 
events setup (like BehaviorSubject or @ngxs/store etc...)
--> 
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

file: **media-library//src/app/app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import {
  NgModule
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Routes,
  RouterModule
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  MediaLibraryPresenterComponent
} from './pages/media-library/media-library-presenter.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: MediaLibraryPresenterComponent
}, ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/models/media-item.ts**

```js
export class MediaItem {
  public id: number;
  public title: string;
  public type: MediaItemTypeEnum;
  public fileType: string;
  public keyword: string;
  public uploadedAt: string;

  public constructor(mediaItem: any) {
    if (mediaItem) {
      Object.assign(this, mediaItem)
    }
  }
}

export enum MediaItemTypeEnum {
  image = 'image',
    document = 'document',
    video = 'video',
    interactiveVideo = 'interactiveVideo',
    audio = 'audio',
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/app.module.ts**

```js
import {
  BrowserModule
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  NgModule
} from '@angular/core';

import {
  AppRoutingModule
} from './app-routing.module';
import {
  AppComponent
} from './app.component';
import {
  MediaLibraryPresenterComponent
} from './pages/media-library/media-library-presenter.component';
import {
  SearchBoxComponent
} from './components/search-box/search-box.component';
import {
  MediaItemsListComponent
} from './components/media-items-list/media-items-list.component';
import {
  DropdownComponent
} from './components/dropdown/dropdown.component';
import {
  TopBarComponent
} from './pages/media-library/top-bar/top-bar.component';
import {
  ClickOutsideDirective
} from './directives/click-outside.directive';
import {
  FormsModule
} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ClickOutsideDirective,
    DropdownComponent,
    MediaItemsListComponent,
    MediaLibraryPresenterComponent,
    SearchBoxComponent,
    TopBarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.component.html**

```html
<div class="selected" (click)="showListToggleHandler($event)">
  <div class="selected__text">
    <div class="selected__label">{{ title }}</div>
    <div class="selected__title">{{ selectedItem ? selectedItem.title: 'None' }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="selected__button" [class.fa-rotate-90]="!showList">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="list" [class.list__show]="showList" (clickOutside)="hideListHandler()">
  <div *ngFor="let item of list; index as i" (click)="selectionHandler(i)" [class.list__item--show]="showList" class="list__item">
    <div class="title">{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div class="list__selected"><i *ngIf="selectedItemIndex==i" class="fas fa-check"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

file: **media-library//src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.component.scss**

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected__label {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.selected__title {
  color: red;
}

.selected__button {
  color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.list {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.list__show {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.list__item {
  height: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list__item--show {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.list__item--show:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/components/dropdown/dropdownItem.ts**

```js
// KK: We save this 'model' not in `models` directory because this is 
// very componnent-inner-view modeel - we don't mix common (api) models with component models
export class DropdownItem {
  public title: string;
  public value: string;

  public constructor(mediaItem: any) {
    if (mediaItem) {
      this.title = mediaItem.title;
      this.value = mediaItem.value;
    }
  }
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.component.ts**

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MediaItem
} from '../../models/media-item';
import {
  DropdownItem
} from './dropdownItem';

@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() list: DropdownItem[] = [];
  @Input() title: string = '';
  @Output() select = new EventEmitter < any > ();

  public selectedItemIndex = 0;
  public selectedItem: DropdownItem = null;

  public showList = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  // KK: inner handler
  public selectionHandler(index) {
    this.selectItem(index);
    this.select.emit({
      item: this.selectedItem,
      index
    });
    this.showList = false;
  }

  // KK: part of component 'interface'
  public selectItem(index) {
    this.selectedItemIndex = index;
    this.selectedItem = this.list[index];
  }

  public getSelected() {
    return {
      item: this.selectedItem,
      index: this.selectedItemIndex
    };
  }

  public showListToggleHandler(event) {
    this.showList = !this.showList;
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  public hideListHandler() {
    this.showList = false;
  }
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/components/media-items-list/media-items-list.component.scss**

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex - direction: column;
  background: white;
  padding - bottom: 5 px;
  padding - top: 5 px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex - direction: column;
  background: #ddd;
  border - radius: 10 px;
  padding: 10 px;
  margin: 10 px;
  margin - top: 5 px;
  margin - bottom: 5 px;
}

.title {
  font - size: 20 px;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  font - size: 14 px;
}

.keywords {
  color: gray;
}

.date {
  margin - right: 10 px;
}

.file - type {
  margin - left: 10 px;
  text - decoration: underline;
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/components/media-items-list/media-items-list.component.html**

```html
<div class="list">
  <div *ngFor="let item of list" class="row">
    <div class="title">{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="date">{{ item.uploadedAt | date}}</div>
      <div class="keywords">{{ item.keywords }}</div>
      <div class="file-type">{{ item.fileType }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

file: **media-library//src/app/components/media-items-list/media-items-list.component.ts**

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MediaItem
} from '../../models/media-item';

@Component({
  selector: 'media-items-list',
  templateUrl: './media-items-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./media-items-list.component.scss']
})
export class MediaItemsListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  @Output() change = new EventEmitter < any > ();
  @Input() list: MediaItem[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {}


}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/components/search-box/search-box.component.ts**

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'search-box',
  templateUrl: './search-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-box.component.scss']
})
export class SearchBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() changeSearch = new EventEmitter < any > ();

  public searchBoxValue = ''

  constructor() {}


  ngOnInit() {}

  // KK: Normally better would be trigger this handler using some deboucne
  // but task demand to fire event every each keystroke
  public changeHandler() {
    this.changeSearch.emit(this.searchBoxValue);
  }

  public clean() {
    this.searchBoxValue = '';
  }
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/components/search-box/search-box.component.html**

```html
<div class="search">
  <input (keyup)="changeHandler()" [(ngModel)]="searchBoxValue" type='text' class="search-box" autofocus placeholder="Search by Title, Keyword or File Type...">
  <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
</div>
```

file: **media-library//src/app/components/search-box/search-box.component.scss**

```css
.search {
  display: flex;
  background: #444;
}

.search-box {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: none;
  background: #eee;
  color: #ccc;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/pages/media-library/media-library-presenter.component.scss**

```css
.main-container {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/pages/media-library/media-library-presenter.component.ts**

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MediaItem
} from '../../models/media-item';
import {
  ApiMediaLibraryService
} from '../../services/api-media-library.service';
import {
  SearchBoxComponent
} from '../../components/search-box/search-box.component';
import {
  TopBarComponent
} from './top-bar/top-bar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'media-library-presenter',
  templateUrl: './media-library-presenter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./media-library-presenter.component.scss']
})
export class MediaLibraryPresenterComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('searchBox', {
    static: false
  }) public searchBox: SearchBoxComponent;
  @ViewChild('topBar', {
    static: false
  }) public topBar: TopBarComponent;

  constructor(public apiMediaLibraryService: ApiMediaLibraryService) {}

  itemsAll = [] as MediaItem[];
  itemsViewed = [] as MediaItem[];
  sortField = '';
  sortAsc = true;
  filterType = '';
  searchString = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiMediaLibraryService.getMediaItemsList().subscribe(items => {
      this.itemsAll = items;
      this.itemsViewed = [...items];
      this.topBarCleanHandler();
    });
  }

  public prepareData() {
    let itemsFound = this.apiMediaLibraryService.search(this.itemsAll, this.searchString);
    let itemsFiltered = this.apiMediaLibraryService.filterBy(itemsFound, this.filterType);
    this.itemsViewed = this.apiMediaLibraryService.sort(itemsFiltered, this.sortField, this.sortAsc);
  }

  public topBarCleanHandler() {
    this.searchString = '';
    this.sortField = 'uploadedAt';
    this.filterType = 'all';
    this.searchBox.clean();
    this.topBar.resetChildren();
    this.sortAsc = true;
    this.prepareData();
  }


  public topBarUpdateSortHandler(event: {
    field: string,
    sortAsc: boolean
  }) {
    this.sortField = event.field;
    this.sortAsc = event.sortAsc;
    this.prepareData();
  }

  public searchBoxChangeHandler(searchString: string) {
    this.searchString = searchString;
    this.prepareData();
  }

  public topBarUpdateFilterHandler(type) {
    this.filterType = type;
    this.prepareData()
  }
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/pages/media-library/media-library-presenter.component.html**

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <search-box #searchBox (changeSearch)="searchBoxChangeHandler($event)">
  </search-box>

  <top-bar (clean)="topBarCleanHandler()" (updateSort)="topBarUpdateSortHandler($event)" (updateFilter)="topBarUpdateFilterHandler($event)" #topBar>
  </top-bar>

  <media-items-list [list]="itemsViewed"></media-items-list>
</div>
```

file: **media-library//src/app/pages/media-library/top-bar/top-bar.component.html**

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="drop-downs-section">
    <dropdown #dropdownFilterBy [list]="filterByList" [title]="'Filter By:'" (select)="filterBySelectionHandler($event)">
    </dropdown>

    <dropdown #dropdownSortBy [list]="sortByList" [title]="'Sort By:'" (select)="sortBySelectionHandler($event)" class="dropdown">
    </dropdown>
  </div>

  <div class="right-buttons">
    <div class="clean__btn" (click)="cleanHandler()">
      <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
      <div class="clean__label">Clear</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort__btn " (click)="toggleSortDirectionHandler()">
      <i *ngIf="!sortAsc" class="fas fa-sort-amount-up-alt"></i>
      <i *ngIf="sortAsc" class="fas fa-sort-amount-down-alt"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

file: **media-library//src/app/pages/media-library/top-bar/top-bar.component.ts**

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  DropdownComponent
} from '../../../components/dropdown/dropdown.component';
import {
  DropdownItem
} from '../../../components/dropdown/dropdownItem';
import {
  MediaItemTypeEnum
} from '../../../models/media-item';

@Component({
  selector: 'top-bar',
  templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.scss']
})
export class TopBarComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('dropdownFilterBy', {
    static: false
  }) public dropdownFilterBy: DropdownComponent;
  @ViewChild('dropdownSortBy', {
    static: false
  }) public dropdownSortBy: DropdownComponent;

  //@Input() selectedItem: MediaItem[] = [];
  @Output() updateSort = new EventEmitter < any > ();
  @Output() updateFilter = new EventEmitter < any > ();
  @Output() clean = new EventEmitter < any > ();

  public filterByList = [] as DropdownItem[];
  public sortByList = [] as DropdownItem[];

  public sortAsc = true;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filterByList = [{
        title: 'All',
        value: 'all'
      },
      {
        title: 'Videos',
        value: < string > MediaItemTypeEnum.video
      },
      {
        title: 'Interactive Videos',
        value: < string > MediaItemTypeEnum.interactiveVideo
      },
      {
        title: 'Audio',
        value: < string > MediaItemTypeEnum.audio
      },
      {
        title: 'Images',
        value: < string > MediaItemTypeEnum.image
      },
      {
        title: 'Documents',
        value: < string > MediaItemTypeEnum.document
      },
    ].map(item => new DropdownItem(item));

    this.sortByList = [{
        title: 'Date upload',
        value: 'uploadedAt'
      },
      {
        title: 'Alphabetical',
        value: 'title'
      },
    ].map(item => new DropdownItem(item));

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.resetChildren();
    });
  }

  public filterBySelectionHandler(event: {
    item: DropdownItem,
    index: number
  }) {
    this.updateFilter.emit(event.item.value);
  }

  public sortBySelectionHandler(event: {
    item: DropdownItem,
    index: number
  }) {
    let e = {
      field: event.item.value,
      sortAsc: this.sortAsc
    }
    this.updateSort.emit(e);
  }

  public cleanHandler() {
    this.clean.emit();
  }

  public toggleSortDirectionHandler() {
    this.sortAsc = !this.sortAsc;

    this.updateSort.emit({
      field: this.dropdownSortBy.getSelected().item.value,
      sortAsc: this.sortAsc
    });
  }

  public resetChildren() {
    this.dropdownFilterBy.selectItem(0)
    this.dropdownSortBy.selectItem(0)
    this.sortAsc = true;
  }
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/pages/media-library/top-bar/top-bar.component.scss**

```css
.drop-downs-section {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  border-top: 2px solid #eee;
  background: #fff;
}

.right-buttons {
  display: flex;
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clean__btn {
  display: flex;
  border-right: 2px solid #eee;
  height: 52px;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.clean__btn:hover {
  color: black
}

.clean__label {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.sort__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.sort__btn:hover {
  color: black
}
```

file: **media-library//src/app/services/api-media-library.service.ts**

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { of ,
  Observable
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  delay,
  map
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  MediaItem
} from '../models/media-item';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiMediaLibraryService {

  constructor() {}

  getMediaItemsList(): Observable < MediaItem[] > {

    // return this.httpClient
    //     .get(this.apiUrl + `/api/media-library/items`)
    //     .pipe(map((res: any) => res.map(item => new MediaItem(item))));

    // mockup
    return of([{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Mona Lisa',
        type: 'image',
        fileType: 'png',
        keywords: 'woman',
        uploadedAt: "2019-07-01 14:20"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'The Last Supper',
        type: 'image',
        fileType: 'jpg',
        keywords: 'jesus people',
        uploadedAt: "2019-07-02 14:20"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Scream',
        type: 'image',
        fileType: 'gif',
        keywords: 'colors face',
        uploadedAt: "2019-07-03 14:20"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Letting Go: The Pathway of Surrender ',
        type: 'document',
        fileType: 'pdf',
        keywords: 'emotions autotherapy',
        uploadedAt: "2019-07-09 14:08"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Three Pillars of Zen',
        type: 'document',
        fileType: 'docx',
        keywords: 'japan mind',
        uploadedAt: "2019-07-08 14:20"
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Dhammapada',
        type: 'document',
        fileType: 'html',
        keywords: 'buddha quotes',
        uploadedAt: "2019-07-07 14:20"
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        title: 'Forest Gump',
        type: 'video',
        fileType: 'avi',
        keywords: 'tom hanks war',
        uploadedAt: "2019-07-06 14:20"
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        title: 'The Matrix',
        type: 'interactiveVideo',
        fileType: 'mov',
        keywords: 'neo trinity phone',
        uploadedAt: "2019-07-05 14:20"
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        title: 'Nic śmiesznego',
        type: 'video',
        fileType: 'mpeg',
        keywords: 'pazura komedia',
        uploadedAt: "2019-07-04 14:20"
      },
    ].map(item => new MediaItem(item))).pipe(delay(500));
  }

  public sort(mediaItems: MediaItem[], field, asc) {
    return [...mediaItems].sort((a: MediaItem, b: MediaItem) =>
      (asc ? 1 : -1) * a[field].localeCompare(b[field])
    );
  }

  public search(mediaItems: MediaItem[], search: string) {
    return mediaItems.filter(item => ['title', 'keywords', 'fileType'].some(field =>
      item[field].toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
    ));
  }

  public filterBy(mediaItems: MediaItem[], type: string) {
    if (type == 'all') return [...mediaItems];
    return mediaItems.filter(item => item.type == type);
  }
}
```

file: **media-library//src/styles.scss**

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
}
```